# How to persist an object between Python and C++?

Tags: python, c++, object, singleton

I am working on a project where half of the project is in Python (the launcher) and the other half is in C++ (the software).

I need to create a C++ object (we'll call it `FooServer`) that is created at the beginning of the Python script and then passed on to the C++ part.

Instantiating the object from Python and calling relative functions has already been achieved, but can I persist the same object from the Python code to the C++ code?

(I have been considering making `FooServer`'s class a Singleton but am still weighing up the pros and cons of this approach).

Example code:

```py
#PYTHON:
import sys, os
from foo_server import *

foo_server_p = FooServer() # or foo_server.getIntance() if using a singleton

foo_server_p.doCoolThings()
# do stuff

os.system("prog.exe") # C++ program compiled to .exe
```

```
//C++:
#include "FooServer.h" // same library as before

// this line is where I would recuperate the foo server object somehow
// Using the singleton approach as an example
fooServer_C = FooServer.getInstance();

fooServer_C.doCoolThings();
# do stuff

fooServer_C.Destroy();
```

Comment: It looks like your Python code starts the C++ program via `os.system("prog.exe")`. Hence, `prog.exe` becomes a process on its own. You cannot simply pass an object (in memory) from one process to another. (Every serious OS will prevent this.)

Comment: @Scheff that's what I feared - but thank you for the answer!